# Изменение нескольких textarea

Tags: javascript, textarea

При вызове `bbcode()`, функция работает только в том `textarea`, где была вызвана первый раз.
Как получать `id` текущего элемента каждый раз? Или может быть можно как-нибудь очищать `id`?

Html код:

```
<ul>
<li class="item" id="item-21351">
    <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="edit">Редактирование</a>
    <div class="content">
        <div class="describe"></div>
    </div>
</li>
<li class="item" id="item-23512">
    <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="edit">Редактирование</a>
    <div class="content">
        <div class="describe"></div>
    </div>
</li>
<li class="item" id="item-12351"">
    <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="edit">Редактирование</a>
    <div class="content">
        <div class="describe"></div>
    </div>
</li>
</ul>
```

Нажатие на `edit` вызывает форму:

```
<form method="post">
    <div class="btn" onclick="bbcode('redit','[tag]','[/tag]')" >[tag]</div>
    <textarea name="redit" class="redit" id="redit"></textarea>
</form>
```

bbcode производит замену выделенного текста

```
<script>
function bbcode(elementID, openTag, closeTag){
    var tarea = document.getElementById( elementID );
    var val = tarea.value;
    var s = tarea.selectionStart;
    var e = tarea.selectionEnd;
    tarea.value = val.substring( 0, s ) + openTag + val.substring( s, e ) + closeTag + val.substring( e, val.length );
}
</script>
```

Comment: У вас несколько `textarea` с одинаковыми id? Так работать не будет

Comment: @sercxjo на то они и Id чтоб были разные, в данном случае лучше привязаться к классу например "redit" и тогда работать будет везде

Answer (score 1):

Вот так должно работать, переделай под себя если что-то не так

```js
$('.edit').click(function() {
  var desc = $(this).parent().find('.describe').html();
  var desc_id = $(this).parent().attr('id');
  $('.redit').val(desc).attr('data-desc-id', desc_id).parent().show();
});
$('.btn').click(function() {
  var desc = $('.redit').val();
  console.log(desc);
  var desc_id = $('.redit').attr('data-desc-id');
  $('#' + desc_id).find('.describe').html(desc);
  $('.redit').val('').parent().hide();
});
```

```html
<ul>
  <li class="item" id="item-21351">
    <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="edit">Редактирование</a>
    <div class="content">
      <div class="describe">чтото1</div>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li class="item" id="item-23512">
    <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="edit">Редактирование</a>
    <div class="content">
      <div class="describe">чтото2</div>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li class="item" id="item-12351">
    <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="edit ">Редактирование</a>
    <div class="content ">
      <div class="describe">чтото3</div>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>

<form method="post " style='display:none;'>
  <input type='text' name="redit" class="redit" id="redit">
  <div class="btn ">save</div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

В функцию `bbcode` первым аргументом вместо `'redit'` передавайте `this`.

Для поиска области ввода лучше использовать относительную адресацию, а не id:

```
function bbcode(element, openTag, closeTag) {
  var tarea = $(element).closest('form').find('textarea.redit');
  ...
}
```